# Curl on Debian 10 returns error html instead of pdf

Tags: ubuntu, curl, debian

I am downloading large batches of pdfs from parliaments. I scraped the pdf addresses and now try to download them.

To do this, I set up a debian instance on a university cloud.

It worked fine for most of them, but for 4 parliaments, I downloaded an error page of having to accept cookies. The result is an html page with pdf file ending that contains mainly the question if I accept cookies.

This error does not happen on either Ubuntu or Windows 10.

Here is the output of the curl on debian:

```
curl -Iv4 http://dokumentation.landtag-mv.de/parldok/dokument/44970/eu_ratspraesidentschaft.pdf

*   Trying 52.57.90.21...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x558926ee0f90)
* Connected to dokumentation.landtag-mv.de (52.57.90.21) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD /parldok/dokument/44970/eu_ratspraesidentschaft.pdf HTTP/1.1
> Host: dokumentation.landtag-mv.de
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private, no-cache
Cache-Control: private, no-cache
< Content-Length: 14447
Content-Length: 14447
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 16:17:41 GMT
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 16:17:41 GMT
```

versus Ubuntu, where I get the pdf

```
$ curl -Iv4 http://dokumentation.landtag-mv.de/parldok/dokument/44970/eu_ratspraesidentschaft.pdf
*   Trying 52.57.90.21:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to dokumentation.landtag-mv.de (52.57.90.21) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD /parldok/dokument/44970/eu_ratspraesidentschaft.pdf HTTP/1.1
> Host: dokumentation.landtag-mv.de
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private, no-cache
Cache-Control: private, no-cache
< Content-Length: 120419
Content-Length: 120419
< Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Type: application/pdf
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 16:01:14 GMT
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 16:01:14 GMT
```

I would be very happy if somebody could tell me what I did wrong

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? How is this related to programming?

Comment: The original script was written in R but noone responded to the request so I tried to make it more general. It is difficult to solve this if the source of the error is unclear.

I originall worked based on the theory that Debian does not have the proper cookies and can't accept them as the popup is javascript that does not interact with curl. 

However, using a cookiefile did not help, and obviously there are no cookies sent even on the Ubuntu machine. I hoped there was somebody on here who knew the issue and give me a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--output` option:

```
curl --output eu_ratspraesidentschaft.pdf http://dokumentation.landtag-mv.de/parldok/dokument/44970/eu_ratspraesidentschaft.pdf
```